# Issues making a template loops with variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple blog to my site and there is no tutorial of how to make one properly, so i'm trying to make one from scratch. My problem right now is to display a template of posts in a loop with variables. Here are the columns of my table:

**Table blog**

1. id
2. user_id
3. date
4. title
5. content

Code of variables:

```
<?php 
// query //
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_id, date, title, content FROM blog");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
// variables //
$user_id = $row['user_id']; //only the id, not the name
$date = $row['date'];
$title = $row['title'];
$content = $row['content'];
// get user_id name //
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
$author = $row2['name']; //last variable
?>
```

What i'm trying to do, is to display them all descendant from id value from the next template vertically:

```
<div id="container">
<div align="center" style="background-color:gray"><b><?php echo $title;?></b></div>
<div align="right">Author: <?php echo $author;?> Date: <?php echo $date;?></div>
<div><?php echo $content;?></div>
</div>
<hr>
```

How could i loop the template with different variables values in a simple page?

Comment: means you want to all records in `blog`?

Comment: i want all the records displayed of the table blog. Descendent from id value.

Comment: Well I guess you learn so I'll give you some hints: 1) Learn about sql `JOIN` - there is no need to get user in additional query. 2) `mysql_fetch_array` returns only 1 row from results, so you need loop through them to get all rows 3) assuming you have variable that will contain your reults you can simply use foreach loop to display all of them 4) mysql_* funciotns are deprecated, try to check mysqli or pdo

Comment: @user3555218 : I posted my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
   <?php
        // query //
        $sql = mysql_query ( "
              SELECT b.id, b.user_id, b.date, b.title, b.content, u.name
              FROM blog b, users u 
              WHERE b.user_id = u.id
              ORDER BY b.id DESC" );
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $sql ) ) {
            // variables //
            $user_id = $row ['user_id']; // only the id, not the name
            $date = $row ['date'];
            $title = $row ['title'];
            $content = $row ['content'];
            $author = $row ['name']; // last variable
        ?>
        <div id="container">
            <div align="center" style="background-color: gray">
                <b><?php echo $title;?></b>
            </div>
            <div align="right">Author: <?php echo $author;?> Date: <?php echo $date;?></div>
            <div><?php echo $content;?></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
<?php
}
?>
```

first make one query for info if you have a lot of rows it will eat resources

```
SELECT b.id, b.user_id, b.date, b.title, b.content, u.name
FROM blog b, users u 
WHERE b.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

then you need to loop the query using:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $sql ) ) {}
```

Comment: blog id is not descendant, could you please fix that. its currently ordered from Low id to High id, i want it High to Low, so new posts will be displayed first.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put your blog table in an array:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_id, date, title, content FROM blog");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $blog[] = $row;
}
```

Then, in the template:

```
<div id="container">
<div align="center" style="background-color:gray"><b><?php echo $title;?></b></div>
<div align="right">Author: <?php echo $author;?> Date: <?php echo $date;?></div>
<div><?php
foreach($blog as $val) {
    echo "<h1>".$val['title']."</h1>"M
    echo $val['content'];
}
?></div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$blogs_table = '<table> <tr> <th>User id</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Title</th> <th>Content</th></tr>';
foreach($records as $row) {
   $blogs_table .= '<tr>';
   $blogs_table .= '<td>' . $row ['user_id'] .'</td>';
   $blogs_table .= '<td>' . $row ['date'] .'</td>';
   $blogs_table .= '<td>' . $row ['title'] .'</td>';
   $blogs_table .= '<td>' . $row ['content'] .'</td>';
   $blogs_table .= '</tr>';
}
$blogs_table .= '</table>';
```

At last you can print your `$blogs_table` table to any where like,

```
<div align="right"><?php echo $blogs_table ?></div>
```